# Extrude curve given by mathematical equation

Tags: bezier-curves

How can I extrude curve given by mathematical equation?

I know how it works for a Bezier Curve.

[image]

I tried to use Solidify modifier but it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the problem seems to be that you need to turn off "u-wrap" and "v-wrap," in the function menu.

I also turned off show wireframe.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the solidify modifier on the xyz surface mesh you made, and it seems to work. [image]

Is that not what you mean?

Comment: I edited my question, this is transparent in my case